# TableView cell size to with respect to label size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and have my own custom cell containing a `UILabel` inside the cell.

I want to increase the tableView row size according to the text in the label.
I am using AutoLayout and my label have 20 padding from left and 8 padding from right,top and bottom.

I am stuck here because the label context is some time small and sometimes very large and i want to increase the size of that row when the text is increased.

Comment: sharing some code might help

Comment: you want the text font size but the row change height, its possible but not good `UI` in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UILabel.numberOfLines` to 0 and add this to your `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir..!! It works just the was i wanted. :)))

Comment: This is not quite right according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html): first of all, you can set those values on the table view instead of returning them from those methods. Second, you should use an actual size for the `estimatedRowHeight` value, and only use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the actual `rowHeight`.